# programmatically setting bluetooth name in Android marshmallow

Tags: android

I want to set bluetooth name in Android marshmallow programmatically with visible to nearby devices with updated name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
bluetoothAdapter.setName("NewDeviceName");//Careful Here
```

1) Don't forget the permission!

2) Bluetooth has to be enabled for this to work.

3) Enabling takes time so you should put setname in a function and only call it when it is enabled. Maybe delay it a bit if you would like to.
Good luck